# Do we have to create db and schema in mongodb before using it in node app using mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-schema

I am a beginner to MEAN stack,I have one doubt that if I want to use any database and schema in my app using mongoose .Is it important that the same database and schema should exist in mongo db before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongodb is schema-less. In other words the schema lives in the application. So no separate schema definitely is required in Mongodb prior to using it. Both database and collection (schema) gets created on the fly while using it.

However if authentication is enabled in Mongodb, then the userid should have sufficient privilege to access the database and create collections within them.